# Android Studio layout editor autocomplete is very slowly

Tags: android-studio

I have an issue with my Android Studio. Layout editing is very slow and laggy. Autocomplete poupups come after 10 seconds and then I select or change something editor freezes for couple of seconds. This started after I updated to Electric El and continues.

Video: https://youtu.be/c5mYLezQE6A

Maybe someone know how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also experienced the same thing, but this problem is fixed in the latest version

Comment: It would be good to add what the "latest version" actually is, so that this answer will be more 'time-proof'.